# In C/C++, is it possible to create simple malware by using pointers to change values of "important" memory addresses?

Tags: c++, c, security, pointers, malware

I'm just learning about pointers in C/C++, and I learned that an uninitialized pointer essentially points to some random memory address. Is it possible to declare the pointer in such a way that it points to some "important" memory address, and then wipe/change the data stored in that address, thus causing problems with the performance of the computer?

Comment: Not on any good operating system. You will get a segfault if you try to access that location

Comment: There's no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: @n.m. C/C++ == C or C++, glad I could clear things up :) .

Comment: @Blondie -- of course, just like those old chestnuts C/Fortran and C/Haskell.

Comment: @David Bowling ha!!!

Comment: @DavidBowling `C or C++` is trivially true for all legal values of C [proof](https://ideone.com/EYXgxe).

Comment: @n.m. -- thankfully `C++ or C++` is also well-defined....

Answer (score 5):

Your operating system is responsible for segmenting your memory such that applications don't have access to memory that they shouldn't have access to.

Therefore, when you try to access these restricted areas of memory, a runtime error will occur (ie. segmentation fault).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if the host operating system allows access to said memory addresses by your program. Most modern operating systems; however, use a system of virtual memory, whereby each process gets an allotment of memory that is transparently mapped by the OS to the real, physical memory of the machine. Accessing, reading, or writing memory outside the bounds imposed by the OS (say to other processes' memory or the kernel itself) will result in a segmentation fault runtime error and typically immediate program termination.